# Persistence of a QMultihash

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering what would be the best way to save a [QMultihash](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmultihash.html).
I was considering saving it as a INI file, using [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html), but is there a better way to do it, make it also easliy loadable ? Serialization maybe ?

What I'm trying to do, btw, is a little UI that would manage images in a folder, used by several algorithms, and keep track of which algorithm is using which images.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to do it, especially for arbitrary key and value types.

Here is an example of how you can convert `QMultiHash<int, double>` to `QVariant` and back:

```
QVariant convert(QMultiHash<int, double> hash) {
  QVariantList variant_hash;
  for(QMultiHash<int, double>::Iterator it = hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); ++it) {
    QVariantList list;
    list << it.key();
    list << it.value();
    variant_hash << QVariant(list);
  }
  return variant_hash;
}

QMultiHash<int, double> convert_back(QVariant variant_hash) {
  QMultiHash<int, double> new_hash;
  foreach(QVariant item, variant_hash.toList()) {
    new_hash.insertMulti(item.toList()[0].toInt(), item.toList()[1].toDouble());
  }
  return new_hash;
}
```

It stores each item of the hash as QVariantList with 2 items (key and value).

Any QVariant can be saved using QSettings. If your key and value types are not supported by QVariant, you need to add their support manually.

If your key type is QString, the code could be simplified because `QHash<QString, QVariant>` can be easily converted to QVariant.

Note that QMultiHash is just a convinient class to use regular QHash with multiple values per key. But QHash is also fully functional for this. So any solution found for QHash can be also applied to QMultiHash.

Comment: Thank you ! I will use both QString as keys (images names) and values (algorithm names), if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Yes, the simplest way is to replace `int` and `double` to `QString` in my code, and replace `toInt` and `toDouble` to `toString`.

Comment: Last question : is there any way to save the QMultiHash in a .ini so it is readable (let's say by opening it with notepad++) ? I know that Qsettings::SetValue() takes one value for one key, so I can't have multiple values for one key, correct ? What could I do instead ?

Comment: You should use `settings.setValue("my_hash", convert(hash));`. QSettings will use this object as a single QVariant value, you don't need to care about keys count. The result will be hardly readable. You should have mentioned in your question that you care about readability. If this is important, it's better to use serialization to JSON.

Comment: No. Why would you think so? JSON is related to JavaScript, but is totally language-independent and is not related to PHP in any way. It's just a good human-readable serialization format.

Comment: OR, I can just use QStringList to add elements (i.e. values) and simple string manipulation (adding a comma separator), then I translate it to QString when setting QSettings values (QStringList sl; (QString)sl; ) I think that should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31593/discussion-between-riateche-and-ctzstef)